# How to create a class to check for keypress

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have successfully created the code to check for keypress but my problem is,
I want it to be in a class so that I can reuse it in other forms as well.
How do I exactly do this?
Here is the code:

```
Private Sub money_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles money.KeyPress
    Dim allowedChars As String = "0123456789" + vbBack
    If allowedChars.IndexOf(e.KeyChar) = -1 Then
        ' Invalid Character
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Lets say `money` is the name of the textbox.
I want to call this function as well in the other forms. How do I pass the variables needed, etc.

Comment: You could handle the `KeyPress` event as a `Public Function` that can be called from any form. Just an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it into `Public`:

```
Public Sub money_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)
    Dim allowedChars As String = "0123456789" + vbBack
    If allowedChars.IndexOf(e.KeyChar) = -1 Then
        ' Invalid Character
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

In Form2:

```
Public Sub form2_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles form2.KeyPress 
    Form1.money_KeyPress(sender, e)
End Sub
```

Comment: how do I declare this `Handles money.KeyPress` if there are no such controls in my `Class.vb` ?

Comment: you mean you don't have the textbox?

Comment: 1) Drag a textbox to the Form1 and rename it "money".  
2) Change "money" to "Form1"?

Comment: Yes, the textbox is in the other form. So, to use the said code I have to do `Imports Form1` wherein the code to trap keypress is written. But the textbox to be checked is in my `Form2.vb`

Comment: okay then, remove the `Handles money.KeyPress` and it will work.

Comment: great! it worked! thanks!!
can you edit your answer and remove `Handles money.KeyPress` from the first block of code so I can accept it..